# Basic ruby array code: Testing if an array has a specific integer

Tags: ruby, arrays, console

I'm trying to test if an array has a specific integer in it. Right now I'm using this test;

```
 def admin?
    current_user.role_ids == [1,2] || current_user.role_ids == [2] || current_user.role_ids == [1,2,5]
  end
```

The code works, but I'd prefer to just test for the integer "2" rather than explicitly write out every possible combination of numbers containing "2". If you have any ruby advice I would really appreciate it. This is the best I could imagine on the fly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you looking for `Array#include?`?

```
current_user.role_ids.include?(2)
```

Comment: Any difference between using include? or member? ? Is one considered slower or less idiomatic?

Comment: There’s little effective difference between the two, but `include?` is more common.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
a.include?(2)
```